# How to get 10 digit Id generated in mongoDB using .NET WebApi

Tags: .net, mongodb, webapi

I am working on an Asp.NET Project with MongoDB as database. I have designed a webapi with fields like ID,Name,Address etc. User will enter these data and the data gets saved in the database. Now I want to generate a 10 digit numeric id automatically after each record insertion by user. I have written this code

```
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    
    public string? Id { get; set; }
```

But this generates a BSon Id of 24Hex symbols like- 637ba231f879c839b44520cc. I want a 10 digit numeric data  to be generated everytime a user record is inserted. Please help me with the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One Way to do it is to write a method to generate a Random 10-digit number every time the user enters these data and assign it as the ID`private string .

```
    GenerateID()
   {
   Random random = new Random();
   int id = random.Next(1000000000, 9999999999);
   return id.ToString();
   }
```

or go with Guid